# Cross-Domain error calling ASP.NET webmethod on http from ASP-Classic site on https

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp-classic

I've got a Windows 2003 server with two sites, different domains. One is an HTTPS site running ASP Classic, the other is an HTTP site, running ASP.NET. I've written a webmethod in ASP.NET that I want to call from the HTTPS site using jQuery/Ajax.

I get a cross domain error when I try to do this. I've added headers on the ASP.NET site for the CORS, but I still can't get the call through.

This is a diagram of my system:

[image]